# update a key in Yaml with list python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

My Yaml looks like this

```
server-params:
    environment: prod
    artifact_version: 0.0.0.*
```

I would like to insert another key named jobs and expected output as below,

```
 server-params:
    environment: prod
    artifact_version: 0.0.0.*
    jobs: ['test','test2']
```

I have tried this

```
jobs_list =['test','test2']

 params = yaml.safe_load(params)
 params['server-params']['jobs']=jobs_list
 yaml.dump(params, default_flow_style=False)


output:
     server-params:
        environment: prod
        artifact_version: 0.0.0.*
        jobs:
        - test
        - test2
```

Comment: @pii_ke I think it's not a duplicate of the question you linked to. shiv455 is getting output, it's just the wrong style

Comment: @tinita oops. I got it now. ✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `default_flow_style` parameter (or set it to `True`) if you want your lists not to expand in your YAML, e.g.:

```
test_yaml = """
server-params:
    environment: prod
    artifact_version: 0.0.0.*
"""

jobs_list = ['test', 'test2']

params = yaml.safe_load(test_yaml)
params['server-params']['jobs'] = jobs_list

print(yaml.dump(params))
```

Which will yield:

```
server-params:
  artifact_version: 0.0.0.*
  environment: prod
  jobs: [test, test2]
```

If you want to keep your YAML ordered, tho, it will depend on the module you're using for all things YAML. If you're using `ruamel.yaml` (and if you're not, you should) use `ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader` as a `Loader` and `ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper` as a `Dumper`. If you're using `PyYAML` you can use the [`yamlordereddictloader`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yamlordereddictloader) module.